# JQuery mobile button icons out of crop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout, mobile

I have a bunch of buttons on my Mobile website, all of which with default icons like these :
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

Everything seems fine when looking at the website on chrome, but on ipod touch or iphone and even Android, the icons seem out of crop like on the next picture. Anyone know how this could be arranged ?

Is this a known bug ?

Thanks !

[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the png images with the new ones.

It's not a bug, if you updated from an earlier version of jquery mobile then you will need to update the 18px and 36px icon sprites. In your case, it is probably the 36px (high dpi) icon set which is scaled in the css with background-size:

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I downloaded the updated javascript file but didnt get the new icons.